# Can an unmarried girl keep Karva Chauth?

Tags: festivals

In our culture, [Karwa Chauth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karva_Chauth) is an important festival for all married women. From sunrise till moonrise, she keeps a fast for the safety of her husband.

But my question is can an unmarried girl keep Karva Chauth?

If yes, are the rituals the same as married women or are there other rituals for unmarried girls?

Comment: "*In our culture*, Karwa Chauth is an important festival for all married women." Which culture are you exactly referring to? Hindu, Indian, regional?  I ask this because Karva Chauth is not performd in Southern parts of India. I only heard people from North perform it.

Comment: Yes unmarried girls can keep karva chauth fast, just that they break the fast by seeing the first star rather than the moon.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I'm not sure if they are same but according to Wikipedia, *It is celebrated as Atla Tadde in Andhra Pradesh.*

Comment: @Aman They are different festivals. On Atla taddi, unmarried women play on swings, make certain number of "atlu" with urad dal similar to dosas, then pray to goddess Uma. Worship of moon and fasting is not seen. Atla Tadde falls one day before Karva Chauth

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I see. Thanks for the info :)